# form values did not clear properly angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to clear my form using clear button. but form validations are cleared well. but entered values not clear. please check my HTML code

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" name="cashBenefitForm" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="save()">
    <input type="text"
    ng-pattern="/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$/" ng-pattern-err-type="invalidMonth"
    maxlength="2" ng-maxlength="2" size="2" ng-minlength="1" 
    placeholder="*No.of months" name="cbMonth"
    ng-model="newcashbenifit.months"
    class="form-control auto-width"/>
<button type="submit">Save </button>
<button type="button" ng-click="clear()"> Clear </button>
</form>
```

my clear function as below

```
 $scope.clear= function () {
$scope.newcashbenifit = {}
$scope.cashBenefitForm.$setPristine();
}
```

when i enter invalid data to text box and after i clicked clear button. that moment error cleared. but text box value did not clear.
[image]

after clicked clear button, errors cleared. but text-box value did not clear. please check below image
[image]

how i clear my form correctly

Comment: Change your button type to `reset` and try.

Comment: There is a confirmation box ,therefore can not and type="reset".

Comment: after confirmation reset your model like `newcashbenifit={}`

Comment: confirmation shows after the form reset.. thats not a solution